# Cron expression to run all the time except every Sunday 10am to 3pm

Tags: cron, cron-task, appdynamics

I need to suppress AppDynamics alerts on every Sunday between 10ma to 3pm and remaining all the time, they should run. To achieve this, i need to write a croj expression to satisfy the condition of "run all the time except every Sunday 10am to 3pm". what could be the cron expression for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cron job to run from Monday to Saturday, here for each hour:

```
0 * * * mon-sat
```

And another to cover the interval you want on Sunday, here one by one hour from 10:00 AM to 03:00 PM:

```
0 10-15/1 * * sun
```